# Which subgroups of a finite reflection group have distingushed coset representatives?

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, coxeter-groups, root-systems

Let $W$ be a finite reflection group with length function $l$ and let $I$ be a set of simple reflections  that generate $W$. Let $\phi$ be an automorphism of $W$ permuting $I$. Consider the orbits of $\phi$ on the set $I$. For each orbit $J$ consider the longest element $s_J$ of the parabolic subgroup $W_J$. Let $W_\phi$ be the subgroup of $W$ generated by the elements $s_J$.

My question is the following:  is there a distingushed coset representatives of the group $W_\phi$?.

Comment: Yes, there is a typo in the title. OP should correct 'cosed' to 'coset'. But the question text itself is formulated clearly and definitely shows the author knows what he is talking about. I'd like to the question to be active, and vote to keep it.

Comment: In this set-up, what is the definition of "distinguished"?   (Maybe a small example would help to clarify what the question is.)

Comment: I guess the intended word was 'distinct' and not 'distinguished'.

Comment: "Unique shortest" is the usual way to distinguish a coset representative, in similar contexts.

Comment: @Jim Distingushed means  minimal coset representatives of $W_\phi$. Maybe this is a better question: is $W_\phi$ a parabolic subgroup of $W$?

Comment: If I understand the set-up correctly, the answer will be negative in general.   Start with symmetric groups, where the question in the header is too open-ended and even your special subgroup $W_\phi$ doesn't seem to admit unique minimal length coset representatives  (Also, $W_\phi$ doesn't have to be parabolic or even generated by reflections: look at $S_4$, for example.)

Comment: @Jim In the proof of proposition 8.1.5 of Carter ''Finite  groups of Lie type'' he said that ${W_J}^F$ has distingushed coset representative in $W^F$. Here $F$ denotes a Frobenius map and $W$ is the Weyl group of a connected reductive algebraic group. In text I did not understand whether he mean that it is true for all $G^F$ conjugacy classes of levi subgroups $L_J$ paremetrized by F-conjugacy classes $N_W(W_J)/W_J$ or just true for the class $ıd$ in $N_W(W_J)/W_J$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments suggest that your notational choices may be obscuring the question,
which I and others have found difficult to untangle.   If stated more precisely, the question might answer itself.

There is some variation of notation and terminology in the liteature, since twisted groups of Lie type are treated a little differently in each of Carter's 1972, 1985 books as well as in Steinberg's work, etc.   The main point here seems to be that for a given Chevalley group with Weyl group $W$, you may have a subgroup $W^F$ of $W$ consisting of fixed points under a Frobenius-type map involving a symmetry of the Coxeter graph as in types $A_n$ for $n \geq 2$, $D_n, E_6$.   (There are more elaborate versions leading to the Suzuki and Ree groups.)    Here $W^F$ is again a finite Coxeter group, though possibly not crystallographic. So the basic theory of reflection groups applies to $W^F$ and its parabolic subgroups.   But this doesn't involve finding coxet representatives for $W^F$ in $W$.   To clarify such matters it would help to focus more on specific cases, which at some point you have to do anyway in the study of these finite groups.

[ADDED] It's worth emphasizing that the Coxeter generators of $W^F$ need not be reflections in $W$ (though they are involutions), so $W^F$ won't be a "reflection subgroup" of $W$.   In particular, the length functions of these two Coxeter groups aren't directly comparable.